# What is the difference between Photoshop PDF and Regular PDF for the iTextSharp?

Tags: c#, .net, pdf, itext

I am using `iTextSharp` to extract text from a PDF file using this code:

```
PdfReader arqPDF = new PdfReader(arqPdf);
int qtdPgs = arqPDF.NumberOfPages;
string textoPDF = "";

for (int i = 1; i <= qtdPgs; i++)
{
    textoPDF += PdfTextExtractor.GetTextFromPage(arqPDF, i, new LocationTextExtractionStrategy());
}
return textoPDF;
```

and everything was just fine.

But recently I've created a PDF using Photoshop to test things up and my output just turned into some Chinese characters:

```
琀 攀 砀 琀 漀 ⤀ 䄀 爀 焀 甀 椀 瘀 漀   瀀 搀 昀
```

The original text is in Portuguese.

Thanks!

Comment: Can you share this PDF? It's a really funny side effect and we'd love to investigate.

Comment: Sure, https://www.dropbox.com/s/fe3ux2scdi2oa1a/text1pdf.pdf?dl=0

Comment: Usually a good first test is copying & pasting from Adobe Reader. If you try that, you also get "⠀琀攀砀琀漀⤀䄀爀焀甀椀瘀漀 瀀搀昀", so the problem very likely is the PDF. Indeed, inspecting the PDF one sees that the font in there explicitly has a **ToUnicode** mapping that maps all character ids to code points far beyond all latin characters.